# Oracle: Trigger to insert values into another Table with one additional auto increment primary key column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have  one Oracle table say

```
Table1
(
roll_number,
myTimestamp
)
```

I have another Oracle table

```
Table2
(
roll_number,
myTimestamp,
recordid --> this is supposed to be an auto increment primary key
)
```

What I want is a trigger which inserts the record inserted into `Table1` into `Table2` as well but with the additional primary key integer column `recordid` being incremented and inserted automatically.
I am able to insert records *without* `Table2` having this additional primary key column constraint using a trigger but when  I try this additional column its giving issues.

I have tried creating an auto increment sequence (say `MySeq`) and tried to insert to create a trigger

```
create trigger MyTrigger
after insert on Table1
for each row
begin
  insert into Table2 values ( :new.roll_number,:new.myTimestamp,select MySeq.nextval into :new.recordid  from dual );
end;
```

but no luck.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your Oracle version? From 12.1 you can define an auto-incrementing identity column without needing to micro-manage sequences.

Comment: My Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it - at least, it works properly on my 11gXE (which database version do you use?):

```
SQL> create table table1 (roll_number number, mytimestamp date);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence myseq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table table2 (roll_number number, mytimestamp date, recordid number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger mytrigger
  2    after insert on table1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into table2 values
  6      (:new.roll_number, :new.mytimestamp, myseq.nextval);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (1, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From table2;

ROLL_NUMBER MYTIMESTAMP           RECORDID
----------- ------------------- ----------
          1 12.03.2021 07:14:42          1

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, instead of `VALUES` use `SELECT`:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger mytrigger
  2    after insert on table1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into table2
  6      select :new.roll_number, :new.mytimestamp, myseq.nextval
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (2, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From table2;

ROLL_NUMBER MYTIMESTAMP           RECORDID
----------- ------------------- ----------
          1 12.03.2021 07:14:42          1
          2 12.03.2021 07:16:00          2

SQL>
```

Comment: If you posted it just like I did (so that we'd see what you really executed an how Oracle responded), it might be easier to assist.

Comment: Its working now. I had make a minor mistake in copying from your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

create or replace trigger  MyTrigger
after insert on Table1
for each row

DECLARE
v_recordid int;

BEGIN
select MySeq.nextval into v_recordid from dual;

insert into Table2 (roll_number,myTimestamp,recordid) values ( :new.roll_number,:new.myTimestamp,v_recordid );
end;

Comment: No Luck : Getting compilation error ```ORA-02287: Sequence Number not allowed here```

Comment: I have changed my answer. It's working now.